# Differentiation of energy expression from wave equation in dimension $d\gt1$

Tags: derivatives, mathematical-physics

From my course in mathematical physics, we define the function: $$e(t)=\int_{B_{c(t_0-t)}(x_0)}dx\left[\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}\right)^2+\frac{c^2}{2}|\nabla u|^2 +\frac{\gamma}{2}u^2\right]$$
With $t\in[0,t_0]$ and $B_{c(t_0-t)}(x_0)$ being the ball centered in $x_0$ with radius $c(t_0-t)$.

We wish to calculate $\frac{d}{dt}e(t)$, the notes go as follows:
$$\frac{d}{dt}e(t)=\frac{d}{dt}\int_{0}^{c(t_0-t)}dr\int_{\partial B_{r}(x_0)}d\sigma\left[\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}\right)^2+\frac{c^2}{2}|\nabla u|^2 +\frac{\gamma}{2}u^2\right]$$
$$=-\frac{c}{2}\int_{\partial B_{c(t_0-t)}(x_0)}d\sigma\left[\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}\right)^2+c^2|\nabla u|^2 +\gamma u^2\right] + \int_{B_{c(t_0-t)}(x_0)}dx\left[\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}\left(\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2}+\gamma u\right)+c^2\nabla u\cdot\nabla\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}\right)\right]$$
Etc, etc...
I find myself slightly unsure about the procedure followed to differentiate, I understand the first term $-\frac{c}{2}\int_{\partial B_{c(t_0-t)}(x_0)}d\sigma\left[\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}\right)^2+c^2|\nabla u|^2 +\gamma u^2\right]$ as the integrand of the $dr$ integral evaluated in its upper extremum $c(t_0 - t)$, where does the second term come from? the:
$$\int_{B_{c(t_0-t)}(x_0)}dx\left[\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}\left(\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2}+\gamma u\right)+c^2\nabla u\cdot\nabla\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}\right)\right]$$
I can see that the integrand here is just the derivative with respect to time of the expression in the original integral, I however am not sure as to where does this term come from, and why we integrate over the whole ball.

Comment: It is an application of the [Reynolds Transport Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reynolds_transport_theorem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given an integral of the form
$$\Phi(t)=\int_{\Omega(t)}F(t,\boldsymbol x)\mathrm d^3\boldsymbol x$$
In order to calculate $\Phi'(t)$ you need to use the Reynolds transport theorem,
$$\Phi'(t)=\int_{\Omega(t)}(\partial_t F)(t,\boldsymbol x)\mathrm d^3\boldsymbol x+\int_{\partial\Omega(t)}\big((\boldsymbol v\cdot\boldsymbol n)F\big)(t,\boldsymbol x)\mathrm d^2\boldsymbol x$$
Where $\Omega(t)$ is a "continuous" set-valued function (this is difficult but not impossible to define rigorously) and $\boldsymbol v(t,\boldsymbol x)$ is the "velocity of the boundary", which again in general is hard to define rigorously, but when
$$\Omega(t)=\mathbb B(\boldsymbol x_0,c(t_0-t))$$
It's pretty clear that
$$\boldsymbol v(t,\boldsymbol x)=-c~\frac{\boldsymbol x}{|\boldsymbol x|}$$
This is where the mysterious surface integral comes from. The volume integral just comes from the Leibniz rule.

Answer (score 0):

It is an application of the Leibniz rule for differentiating under the sign of integral, cfr. [Leibniz Integral Rule, Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Just noticed you are the asker. My mistake

Comment: @K.defaoite As you pointed out, the "Reynolds Transport Theorem" is the result that we're actually utilizing here. After some research, before posting my answer, it was however clear to me that we're making use of a generalized version of Leibniz's integral rule (which I unjustifiedly supposed to hold) so I didn't investigate further. If you desire to post your comment as an answer I'll be happy to accept it.